# Comparing double values in java gives odd answer

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a linked list implementation program, in which I am comparing two Object values. List can have any type of Object value. Then I have a function to remove duplicates. While comparing the double values it doesn't give true where as it works for all other types.
Here is the code snippet:

```
//Method to remove duplicates using two pointers
public void removeDups2(){
    if(head.getNextNode() == null)
        return;

    Node currentNode = head, runnerNode;
    while(currentNode != null){
        runnerNode = currentNode;
        while(runnerNode.getNextNode() != null){
            if(runnerNode.getNextNode().getValue() == currentNode.getValue()){
                runnerNode.setNextNode(runnerNode.getNextNode().getNextNode());
                listcount--;
            }
            else{
                runnerNode = runnerNode.getNextNode();
            }
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    }
}
```

However if I replace the if condition with **.equals()** then it works.

```
if((runnerNode.getNextNode().getValue()).equals(currentNode.getValue())){
```

I tried testing this below:

```
double a = 159.25, b = 159.25;
System.out.println(a == b);
```

and it gives **true** output.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

When using `==` to compare to objects, you are not testing if they are equivalent - just if they point to the same object. By using `.Equals`, you are testing if the values are equivalent. Your test of the `double` values is different than comparing objects since you are comparing primitive types instead of object types